# Consume from two flink dataStream based on priority or round robin way

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two flink `dataStream`. For ex: `dataStream1` and `dataStream2`. I want to union both the Streams into 1 stream so that I can process them using the same process functions as the dag of both `dataStream` is the same.

As of now, I need equal priority of consumption of messages for either stream.
The producer of dataStream2 produces 10 messages per minute, while the producer of dataStream1 produces 1000 messages per second. Also, dataTypes are the same for both dataStreams.DataSteam2 more of a high priority queue that should be consumed asap. There is no relation between messages of dataStream1 and dataStream2

Does `dataStream1.union(dataStream2)` will produce a Stream that will have elements of both Streams?

Comment: Welcome! And what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: Where do the datastreams come from? Directly from source components?

Comment: The dataStreams are source component of pulsar topics.

Comment: @Christophe Does .union() will produce stream which will be round robin of both the dataStream.

Comment: @NischalKumar the `union()` does not introduce any regulations IIRC. So if one of Your sources will produce elements faster than the other then it won't regulate the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution to this problem, yet not exactly the most efficient one depending on the exact specification of the sources for Your data, may be connecting the two streams. In this solution, You could use the `CoProcessFunction`, which will invoke separate methods for each of the connected streams.

In this solution, You could simply buffer the elements of one stream until they can be produced (for example in round-robin manner). But keep in mind that this may be quite inefficient if there is a very big difference between the frequency in which sources produce events.

Comment: CoProcessFunction would make sense when separate business logic is required for each of the connected streams. In my case, the business logic is completely the same.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have each method in the `CoProcessFunction` call a common method to process the record? Your comment here makes me feel like there's something more to your problem than what's being described above.

Comment: Using CoProcessFunction would make sense when dataTypes are different. In my use case, dataStram1 has same datatype as dataStream2, but dataStream1 producer produces 10^3 messages per second, while dataStream2 produces 10 messages per minute. I want a round-robin strategy so that dataSteam2 is also consumed along with dataSteam1 message. As the rate of dataStream2 is very low, it should get processed the moment it arrives.

Comment: @NischalKumar not exactly, since CoProcessFunction is actually one of the functions that due to the presence of  `Collector` will allow you to not emit the output for the given stream but simply buffer it and wait for the input from the other stream.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the two `DataStream`s have different types of elements, though you didn't specify that explicitly. If that's the case, then create an `Either<stream1 type, stream2 type>` via a `MapFunction` on each stream, then `union()` the two streams. You won't get exact intermingling of the two, as Flink will alternate consuming from each stream's network buffer.

If you really want nicely mixed streams, then (as others have noted) you'll need to buffer incoming elements via state, and also apply some heuristics to avoid over-buffering if for any reason (e.g. differing network latency, or more likely different performance between the two sources) you have very different data rates between the two streams.

Comment: dataTypes are same for both dataStreams

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a custom operator that implements the `InputSelectable` interface in order to reduce the amount of buffering needed. I've included an example below that implements interleaving without any buffering, but be sure to read the caveat in the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/InputSelectable.html) which explains that

> ... the operator may receive some data that it does not currently want to process ...

In other words, this simple example can't be relied upon to really work as is.

```
public class Alternate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<Long> positive = env.generateSequence(1L, 100L);
        DataStream<Long> negative = env.generateSequence(-100L, -1L);

        AlternatingTwoInputStreamOperator op = new AlternatingTwoInputStreamOperator();

        positive
            .connect(negative)
            .transform("Hack that needs buffering", Types.LONG, op)
            .print();

        env.execute();
    }
}

class AlternatingTwoInputStreamOperator extends AbstractStreamOperator<Long>
        implements TwoInputStreamOperator<Long, Long, Long>, InputSelectable {

    private InputSelection nextSelection = InputSelection.FIRST;

    @Override
    public void processElement1(StreamRecord<Long> element) throws Exception {
        output.collect(element);
        nextSelection = InputSelection.SECOND;
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(StreamRecord<Long> element) throws Exception {
        output.collect(element);
        nextSelection = InputSelection.FIRST;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSelection nextSelection() {
        return this.nextSelection;
    }
}
```

Note also that `InputSelectable` was added in Flink 1.9.0.