# How to prioritize StreamRecord selection of One Stream over another based on availability?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Given Two Streams `A` and `B` in Flink, I want to process Stream `A` until it is empty and start reading `B` until there are records arriving at `A`.

I am looking for a loose contract. I found `InputSelectable` interface seems to provide the notion of providing priority of reads.

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742165/consume-from-two-flink-datastream-based-on-priority-or-round-robin-way), I see a round-robin implementation of Stream reads. However, I am unsure from the documentation on what happens if one of the streams becomes empty?, does the operator stop processing records altogether?

One naive way to implement this would be to use Timers to poll and detect inactivity of a Stream before switching to a lower priority stream but this might be too inefficient.

Qs:

1. Is there a built-in stream operator to achieve the above use case?
2. What is the behavior of InputSelectable if one input becomes empty?
3. Is Timer-based InputSelectable implementation the way to go?

Comment: Can You tell what kind of sources are You going to use and how would You like to detect the emptiness of the stream??

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. No.
2. I don't believe the behavior is specified / guaranteed.
3. Should be workable, but you need to be careful.

It's possible to get yourself into trouble with `InputSelectable`. If you completely starve one of the inputs, you will prevent checkpoint barrier alignment from ever completing, and thereby block checkpointing. It is also possible to build topologies that deadlock.

And you may want to consider the interaction of the network buffer timeout with your timers. I'm thinking you may want to arrange for the network buffer timeout for stream `A` to be something less than the timeout you use for your timers.